# How to change the default class name in div which created by widget in yii1?

Tags: yii1.x

Hi i am new to Yii 1 framework. For displaying the table and pagination i am using below code. Its working fine. But the problem is this widget creating one div by defaultly with id="yw0" class="list-view".
How to change "list-view" class in yii1?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array('dataProvider' => $autoAccessDataProvider, 'itemView' => '_autoAccessUsers', 'itemsTagName' => 'table', 'itemsCssClass' => 'container-autoaccess-users', 'template' => "{items}\n{pager}", 'ajaxUpdate' => true, 'viewData' => array('dataProvider' => $autoAccessDataProvider)));
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance.